# Find out a Real symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How To Find Out：$$B=A^5-A^4-2A^3+I_3$$
given: $A\in M_3(R),trA=2, detA=-2,A\alpha=\alpha,\alpha=(1,-2,1)^T,$.

To solve this question，it takes me for 2 hours and i still can't get through it.can somebody do me a favor?

Comment: Please check the given data is accurate and you left no detail off.

Comment: all detail is on here，i have already worked it out.it's not easy...@Timbuc

Comment: I can write $B$ in terms of $A^2$, $A$, and $I$, but I haven't been able to find $B$ exactly.

Comment: $\alpha_1 =(1,-2,1)^T$, $\alpha_2 =(2,1,0)^T$, $\alpha_3 =(-1,0,1)^T$, S.T. $B\alpha_1=-\alpha_1$, $B\alpha_2=\alpha_2$, $B\alpha_3=\alpha_3$, let $P=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ $$B=P^{-1}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)P$$ @Michael Albanese

Comment: Where did you get $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ from? How do you know what $A\alpha_2$ or $B\alpha_2$ is?

Comment: $trA=2, detA=-2$ and $A\alpha=\alpha$,s.t,so the Eigenvalues of A are$ 1,-1,2.$ Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of B can be found by 1,-1,2 for
$B\alpha=(A^5-A^4-2A^3+I_3)\alpha=-\alpha,e.t$@ Michael Albanese

Answer (score 0):

claim: the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $det(\lambda I - A) = \lambda^3 - 2\lambda^2 -\lambda + 2 = (\lambda -1)^2(\lambda + 2).$

we know $det(\lambda I - A) = \lambda^3 - tr(A) \lambda^2 + k\lambda - det(A),$ where $k$ is the sum of $2 \times 2$ principal minors to be determined. we are given $A\alpha = \alpha, \alpha  \neq 0$ so $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue. putting $\lambda = 1$ in the characteristic equation gives $k = -1$ and the claim is proved.

by cayley-hamilton, $A^3 = 2A^2 + A - 2I$ so $A^4 = 2A^3 + A^2 - 2A = 2(2A^2 + A - 2I) + A^2 - 2A = 5A^2 - 4I,\ A^5 = 5A^3 - 4A = 5(2A^2+A-2I) - 4A = 10A^2 + A - 10I$

therefore $B = A^5 - A^4- 2A^3 + I = (10A^2 + A - 10I) -(5A^2 - 4A) -2(2A^2 + A - 2I) + I = A^2 +3A -5I$

this is the farthest i can go without any information on the minimal polynomial of $A$